# How do I add a panel to a BaseFrame from a second class

Tags: c#, object, user-controls, reference, flowlayoutpanel

How to I change the BasePanel of a Windows Form Program to public, and to non static, so that I can reference it like a object?

For example, I have a basePanel which, using the designer in Visual Studios 2010, has a flowLayoutPanel on it. I also have a second Class, "TaskDetails", which contains a button, "ButtonOne". When ButtonOne is pressed, it creates a new TaskDetails form. when details are filled out, and the create new task button is pressed, I want to create a new User Control Object which I can add to the FlowLayoutPanel.

However, I don't know how to refer to FlowLayoutPanel, without knowing the object name of basePanel.

Comment: No need  to include the language in the title -- the tags will take care of that.

Comment: What is BasePanel? Is it a Panel object?